# Are there any good soft keyboards?

Tags: keyboard, hardware-rec, noise

My office is right next to my daughter's room and my typing sometimes wakes her up. Are there any soft keyboards that anyone recommends that would not make as much sound as a regular keyboard when typing?

Comment: I'm in search of one of those (and a mouse too) for quote a while now. There are some quiet keyboard, but I want one where you can feel you presses a key, not those membrane types. ...

Comment: The new Apple Magic Mouse should be very quiet, not having any phisical button.

Comment: A different approach would be to purchase a white noise generator to put in your daughter's room. I'm a lucky dad, my kids can sleep through anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Logitech Illuminated](http://www.logitech.com/index.cfm/keyboards/keyboard/devices/4740&cl=US,EN) keyboard - for me and my parents at least - is a very quiet keyboard.  Pricey though.